# Access denied to NFC finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"

Tags: android, nfc, xiaomi

I’m developing an Android App that uses NFC to read a ISO/IEC 14443 type A Card emulated

```
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.cardemulation.CardEmulation;
import android.nfc.tech.NfcA;
import android.nfc.tech.IsoDep;
```

The App works perfect on Samsung S8 or even at old Sony Xperia. But on Xiaomi Redmi note 9 appears the next error. After the error, we do not receive any call back with ISO/IEC 14443 type A approach.

On Android 10:

```
> I/FeatureParser: can't find merlinnfc.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /vendor/etc/device_features
> E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.df.effect.conflict"
```

On Android 11:

```
> E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.vendor.pref_scale_resolution"
```

Any advice? Thanks

Comment: You need to show some more code to help people identify your problem as there are a number of ways to read NFC cards, and for reading you don't need `android.nfc.cardemulation.CardEmulation`. And have you tried a real NcfA card like a Type2 or Type4A?

Comment: Maybe it is only a guess, but it seems it has something to do also with the call of dialogs (I dont't know, maybe layout related) or fragments, check it out. It is also interesting that this seems to happen mainly (if not only) in Xiaomi devices, as my research pointed. I am struggling with this here also, also a Xiaomi device. Upvoted.

Comment: Did you find the answer eventually.